# Android large application

Tags: android, tabs

I wont to create Android application with many screen.
I have web site with many page about 30 page. and I wont to create similar in Android.

How can I make it correct?

I am trying make following:

```
private String[] tabs = { "Service", "Employee", "Product", "Client", "Remainders" };

// Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
```

now I wont put in other subtabs in each tab.

```
private String[] subtabs = { "Dictionary", "Data", "Acton", "Report" };
```

for example `"Service"` can have 4 tabs `"Dictionary", "Data", "Acton", "Report"`

Comment: navigation drawer may help u....

Answer (score 0):

In case you have access to the website files and it uses HTML,CSS and Javascript, you can use PhoneGap to have a Native Application.The website and the Application would have the same look and feel.